# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in python

Tags: python, function

Good I try to create a function with a list of clients where when placing the name in the function gives me the name of the client. But I get an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
listclient = ["john","william","tom"]

def SearchClient(nameclient,listclient):
  for counter in range(len(listclient)):
    if(listclient[counter]["name"]==nameclient):
      return listclient[counter]

  return None

client = SearchClient("tom",listclient)
print("find client:" +client["name"])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I tried to change the "name" of the condition to "nameclient" but it didn't work, and I can't change the data type.

Comment: `listclient[counter]` is a string, what exactly do you expect `listclient[counter]["name"]` to do? Same goes for `client` and `client["name"]`. Where did you get the idea to use `"name"` at all here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find if a particular client is in your client list, this is how you do it:

```
def SearchClient(nameclient, listclient):
    if nameclient in listclient:
        return f'Found client {nameclient} in list of clients.'
    return f'Did not find client {nameclient} in list of clients.'


listclient = ["john","william","tom"]
print(SearchClient("john",listclient))

#prints: Found client john in list of clients.
```